# Pandas Merge two csv with maintain hierarchy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

> I have a below requirement. if get any help here much appreciated and thanks in advance. 
>   Requirement: I have two csvs need to merge both csv with continued parent field. **
>
> i have tried to merge the two csv using key as position and market. but i dont know how to add add the parent info form other csv as a continuation.
>
> CSV 1

```
Position    ParPosition    Market
Pos1        PPos1           US
Pos2        PPos2           US
Pos3        PPos3           US
Pos4        PPos4           US
Pos5        PPos5           US
PPos1       PPPos1          US
PPos2       PPPos1          US
PPos3       PPPos1          US
PPos4       PPPos1          US
PPos5       PPPos1          US
PPPos1                      US
Pos1        PPos1           IN
Pos2        PPos2           IN
Pos3        PPos3           IN
Pos4        PPos4           IN
Pos5        PPos5           IN
PPos1       PPPos1          IN
PPos2       PPPos1          IN
PPos3       PPPos1          IN
PPos4       PPPos1          IN
PPos5       PPPos1          IN
PPPos1                      IN
```

> csv2

```
Position    ParPosition       Market
Org1            Org2            US
Org2            Org3            US
Org3                            US
Org1            Org2            IN
Org2            Org3            IN
Org3                            IN
```

> Output required

```
Position    ParPosition       Market
Pos1            PPos1           US
Pos2            PPos2           US
Pos3            PPos3           US
Pos4            PPos4           US
Pos5            PPos5           US
PPos1           PPPos1          US
PPos2           PPPos1          US
PPos3           PPPos1          US
PPos4           PPPos1          US
PPos5           PPPos1          US
PPPos1          Org1            US
Org1            Org2            US
Org2            Org3            US
Org3                            US
Pos1            PPos1           IN
Pos2            PPos2           IN
Pos3            PPos3           IN
Pos4            PPos4           IN
Pos5            PPos5           IN
PPos1           PPPos1          IN
PPos2           PPPos1          IN
PPos3           PPPos1          IN
PPos4           PPPos1          IN
PPos5           PPPos1          IN
PPPos1          Org1            IN
Org1            Org2            IN
Org2            Org3            IN
Org3                            IN
```

> Thanks in Advance